# Extracting content from DOCX into Python Code

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, docx

I have been learning how to create DOCX files using Python.
However, I have a document that I want to automate the regular editing by using python. The editing (deleting or adding) needs to be conducted based on terms found in an excel spreadsheet.

The Document I have is around 25 pages, with different formats, tables, paragraphs, headings, and some images. Is there a way to extract all of this into python code, where I can then add terms based on an excel spreadsheet on what to print or leave in the docx file?

Main concern is DOCX content --> Python CODE

Example:
If the document I was reading only contains a paragraph saying "Test"
The code would generate a separate new code that would state:
document.add_paragraph('Test')

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you want to do with the text. If you want to put it back "in-place" to a docx, you'll want to have a look at `python-docx` or edit the xml itself.

If you're willing to rebuild the tree document structure from some pile of text, several python libraries will pull the text for you (python-docx, docx2txt, docx2python).

Here's how you might edit the text in docx2python

```
from docx2python import docx2python
from docx2python.iterators import enum_paragraphs

content = docx2python('input.docx').document

for (i, j, k), paragraph in enum_paragraphs(content):
    content[i][j][k] = transforming_function(paragraph)
```